# How to install pipelight after closing the terminal the first time

Tags: dpkg, pipelight

I opened the terminal and did everything right, but accidentally exited out of the process while it was asking for the license and agreements.  Now, whenever I try to redo the process, it isn't able to get lock `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` open.

Comment: Follow the steps on the answer given above (that is, remove the lock manually). Then try reinstalling Pipelight (if you added a PPA you don't need to add it again).

Answer (score 0):

Even if the terminal has closed, you can open another terminal to continue the process.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi

sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

You'll also need a plugin like "*User Agent Overrider*" to make websites believe you are running Windows instead of Linux.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-overrider/